# How to change label value based on two dropdown list in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#method,#paper").on("change", function(){

               var paper= $('option:selected',this).text()                          
               var method = $('option:selected', this).text()


                   if (method == "1 month") {
                   $('#duration').html("150");
               } else if (method == "3 month" ) {
                   $('#duration').html("450");
               }
                 else if (method == "6 month"  ) {
                   $('#duration').html("900"); 
               }
                 else if (method == "1 year" ) {
                   $('#duration').html("1800");
               }

           });
   });    
</script>
```

Comment: please include the relevant HTML as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `.text()`.

Details: https://api.jquery.com/text/

```
if (method == "1 month") {
  $('#duration').text("150");
}
```